# App usage time per user level on react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-analytics

I am working on a react native app, I wanted to find out a way to get the app usage time of our app on a user basis.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? There is nothing here to tell us about what platform, language or anything about what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Use react native's **AppState** to check if the app is active or in background.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppState, Text} from 'react-native';

class AppStateExample extends Component {
  state = {
    appState: AppState.currentState,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (
      this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) &&
      nextAppState === 'active'
    ) {

      console.log('App has come to the foreground!. save this time');
    }
    console.log('App sent to the background!. save this time. ');
    /// difference between both the times is the time spent by user on app
    this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
  };

  render() {
    return <Text>Current state is: {this.state.appState}</Text>;
  }
}
```